# Formateo de tabulaciones en vsCode

Tags: formato

Me gustaría saber como puedo modificar las tabulaciones cuando guardo un archivo, por defecto me pone 4 espacios pero quiero 2 cada vez que guarde.

No encuentro nada y debería de ser algo sencillo por tema formateo.

Un saludo y muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Desde el menú "Settings..." tienes varias opciones relacionadas:

1. Editor: Insert Spaces

Si está activado insertará espacios en vez de tabuladores.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2. Editor: Tab Size

Determina cuantos espacios se insertarán al pulsar tabulador.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

3. Editor: Detect Indentation

Tienes que desactivarlo para poder controlar las anteriores opciones de manera manual, ya que si está activado, el editor determinará el modo de funcionamiento en función del contenido.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]